# How to get html spellcheck attribute work in iframe?

Tags: iframe, spell-checking

I have a chrome extension. 
spellcheck="true" attribute works for input fields if I insert html input fields in page's html. And it properly underlines spelling mistakes. 
But I need to make it work inside iframe. I am inserting iframe into page and doing spellcheck="true" for input fields inside the iframe; where it's not working. 
Can you please suggest why it's not working and a solution ?
Thank you!

Comment: Any help guys ?

Comment: Any help guys ?

Comment: Did you get to fix this issue? If so can you please let me know